# Access Node properties within html.tpl.php in Drupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal-7, nodes

I am trying to access the current $node variables in the html.tpl.php within Drupal 7. The problem is that I am running a Analytics software in the backend for which I've to record each page's analytics from html.tpl.php.

If there's a normal page, I have to record generic attributes but if it's a node, I need the following things in the `html.tpl.php`:-

- Title of the Content (Node)
- Content Type of the Content

I can do this in `node.tpl.php` through `$node->type;`, but unfortunately I need it in html.tpl.php.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to html.tpl.php

```
  <?

      $node = node_load(arg(1));
      print $node->type;

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah the answer from @hkinterview could be a possibility.

node_load($node_id) loads the node with the id $node_id, but you have to make sure that arg(1) is the id of the node, for example on view pages this isnt the case.

So you can write

```
if(arg(1) && is_numeric(arg(1))){
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $type = $node->type;
  $title = $node->title;
}
```